# saving survey123 data programmatically using python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, arcrest

I'm recording data using the Survey123 app which logs data into a standard ESRI rest service, stored in my AGOL account. I would like to save this data an SDE dataset. Is it possible to do so using python (arcpy or other library)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily done with ArcREST.

```
from arcrest.manageorg import Administration
from arcrest import AGOLTokenSecurityHandler
from arcrest.agol import FeatureService
from arcrest.common.filters import LayerDefinitionFilter

def download_features(fs_url,where_clause,out_path):
    '''downloads a hosted service features into a feature class'''
    agol_securityHandler = AGOLTokenSecurityHandler('user','pwd','http://company.maps.arcgis.com/')
    agol_org_obj = Administration(securityHandler=agol_securityHandler,initialize=True)

    fs = FeatureService(url=fs_url,securityHandler=agol_securityHandler,initialize=True)

    ldf = LayerDefinitionFilter()
    ldf.addFilter(0, where=where_clause)

    queryResults = fs.query(layerDefsFilter=ldf,returnCountOnly=False,returnGeometry=True)
    result = queryResults[0].save(r'in_memory','SampleCities')
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(result,out_path)
```

This is the function that will do the work. I query the hosted feature service with an SQL where clause. If you need to take all of your features, just use the `1=1` for the where clause. I like writing first to `in_memory` and then copying from there into the SDE.

Now calling the function:

```
out_path = r'C:\GIS\Temp\yourdb.sde\yourdb.dbo.SampleCities'
fs_url = r'http://services3.arcgis.com/companyid/arcgis/rest/services/Cities/FeatureServer'
where_clause = "POP1990 > 1000000"
download_features(fs_url,where_clause,out_path)
```