# Survey123 data with REST API

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-survey123

I need to access the data collected in Survey123. I reached out to ESRI and they have no training available on this topic and the documentation was lacking at best. I saw that there was a python script mentioned in the documentation. Would prefer to bypass python and interact with the REST API directly as I am trying to automate a scheduled export of the data to a reporting tool.
If the REST API can't be used are there any other ways to extract data from Survey123 that can be automated?

Based on what I have seen thus far accessing the data from the REST API for Survey123 data is poorly documented and obfuscated. I would not recommend using Survey123 if the goal is to access the data collected.

Comment: Your question is a little broad and could use some focus. What output format do you want? Talking about the REST API means you're going to get back JSON - does your reporting tool accept JSON or will you need to convert it after that? Or can your tool make an HTTP request to a RESTful endpoint? Most people when automating would use a Python script to make an HTTP request to the REST API. (But there are other ways) --- Have you seen the "export" menu option in the Item details page? Do you want one of those formats? This can be automated (using something like Python)

Comment: I was planning on using cUrl to download the data. Parameters for the cUrl would be passed in by a shell script. Whatever format the API is able to generate will be consumed and inserted into a database for reporting whether it is JSON, CSV, binary, etc. What matter most is actually getting data from Survey123 without a person having to click the button.

Comment: You may consider using FME. There is a AGOL connector available that can download data and then manipulate / convert / etc to put into your local db, save as a specific format to disk, etc.

Comment: Also, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195916/saving-survey123-data-programmatically-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind checking if this helps https://developers.arcgis.com/survey123/api-reference/report/ ? The Data tab of the Survey123 website also uses the same REST API to generate reports, you might also observe details there.